# How to hurt someone protected by a full body armor?

Tags: steel

For the purpose of a fantasy novel set in our era, I need to know how a full body armor (not a plate one,but more like Iron man, covering all the body without holes) can be pierced and by what weapons (the weapon has to be used by a single civilian man, in a duel, so no rockets, but a stick of dynamite ok). In addition, if the armor is electrocuted, can the steel melt or be weakened and so have the penetration of the weapon improved (don't answer the armor wielder will be dead by the electrocution because he's undead and to definitely die his skull has to be destroyed) ?

Comment: Cut the head off with a light saber.

Comment: Ironman doesn't follow the laws of physics.  Any blunt damage will hurt a person inside armor from the g forces (like collision with a car), and damage the armor itself.  Armor that isn't inches thick will be penetrated by large/fast enough projectiles, tank penetrators will penetrate 355mm.  Explosives will damage anything, especially joints.

Comment: You may want to look up people who are talking about medieval combat. Essentially you can still attack the joints, even if that is impossible you can still immobilize or exhaust a fighter. But you will get a better answer of you close this and open it in worldbuilding SE

Comment: just push them down a flight of stairs

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site, where we focus more on application of engineering principles in real-world cases. You might have better luck in [WorldBuilding.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Armor can be penetrated or bypassed in tons of ways.

- Shaped charges
- Hard, fast projectiles
- High energy projectiles that don't penetrate but cause spalling on the inner surface
- It can be cut with plasma, a fuel/oxygen torch or laser
- It can be machined with drills and saws, just like anything else
- Explosives or blunt trauma may cause damage even if the armor is not penetrated.
- Acid may disolve it (slowly)
- Chemical weapons may bypass it
- Extreme cold might make it brittle (in combination with some other attack)
- A molotov cocktail or flamethrower may cook the wearer and rob them of oxygen, even if the armor can withstand the temperature.
- The armored person may be imobilized by a net, hardening foam, a heavy object, etc. Even if not injured.
- The armor joints may have greater range of motion than the wearer, leaving the person vulnerable to twisting or hyper extension of their joints.